# WebView: Error loading page - ERR NAME NOT RESOLVED

Tags: react-native

I get this error:

Encountered an error loading page - ERR NAME NOT RESOLVED

Why ?

```
  import { WebView } from 'react-native';

  render() {
    return (
    <WebView
      source={{uri: 'https://github.com/facebook/react-native'}}
      style={{marginTop: 20}}
    />
    );
  }
}
```

Why ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need more than just a `render` method. This logic should be inside of a class that extends `Component` from React. Additionally, you'll want to register this component via the `AppRegistry` from React Native if this is the root of your app:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { AppRegistry, WebView } from 'react-native';

class App extends Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <WebView
                source={{uri: 'https://github.com/facebook/react-native'}}
                style={{marginTop: 20}}/>
        );
    }
}

AppRegistry.registerComponent('App', () => App);
```

If this component is not the root of your app, you can remove the last line and exclude `AppRegistry` from your imports.

Comment: @xRobot There must be something else wrong with your project structure then because I've tested this code and it definitely works `¯\_(ツ)_/¯`

Comment: I have just deleted all the code and I have used only your code. I still get the same error.

Comment: @xRobot See https://rnplay.org/apps/VmQthw to view it working in action. Not sure what else to tell you.

Comment: What device you testing on? Have you tried another device - does it work in simulator. I've had issues with webview with some Huawei Phones .

Answer (score -1):

Have you tried turning it off and on again? For real, kill your index.android.js bundle, kill your emulator and start them back up again. That fixed this problem for me.

Answer (score -1):

This issue can happen if your internet connection is weak.

[Refer this link](https://github.com/react-native-webview/react-native-webview/issues/1619#issuecomment-1683604784) to handle this